# Center text with drawableLeft

Tags: android

I can't get text centered while I have drawableleft image next to it. And how to add padding left for that image too?

Here's my xml code:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/matematikaText"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0px"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="#4CAF50"
    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/mathico"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:height="@dimen/abc_action_bar_default_height"
    android:padding="0dp"
    android:text="Matemātika"       
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
```

Answer (score 1):

To add padding to drawable,

```
android:drawablePadding="8dp"
```

Answer (score -1):

set gravity to

android:gravity="center"